# Algorithmicx - Indentation problem when using \skipnumber to suppress line numbers?

Tags: indentation, algorithmicx

I need to suppress the line numbers for `\For` loops and `\If` statements in my algorithm. I found the `\skipnumber` command online which does the job, however for some reason it messes up the indentation of my next `\State` statement. I also see that for some reason there is no space between the `\Else` statement and the text. I have attached a screenshot of the problem and the relevant code. Any ideas?

[image: The problem]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\skipnumber}[2][1]{%
{\renewcommand*{\alglinenumber}[1]{}\State #2}%
\addtocounter{ALG@line}{-#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h!]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
%SOME OTHER STUFF HERE
\State \textbf{Apply threshold of $\pm t$ around centre gradient value ($G_c$) in a $3\times3$ neighbourhood to determine $S_{GLTP}$ codes for the image} 
\skipnumber[5]{\ForAll{gradient magnitude value ($G_i$) around $G_c$}
\If{$G_i > G_c + t$} $S_{GLTP}(i)\gets+1$ 
\ElsIf{$G_i < G_c - t$}  $S_{GLTP}(i)\gets-1$
\Else $S_{GLTP}(i)\gets 0$ 
\EndIf
\EndFor}
\Statex \textbf{repeat} for each $3\times3$ neighbourhood
\Statex
\State \textbf{Compute positive ($P_{GLTP}$) and negative ($N_{GLTP}$) $GLTP$   coded image representations from $S_{GLTP}$ values}
\skipnumber[5]{\ForAll{$S_{GLTP}(i)$ value in a $3\times3$ neighbourhood}
\If {$S_{GLTP}(i)>0$} $S_P(i)\gets1$ \& $S_N(i)\gets0$
\ElsIf {$S_{GLTP}(i)<0$} $S_P(i)\gets0$ \& $S_N(i)\gets1$
\Else $S_P(i)\gets0$ \& $S_N(i)\gets0$ \EndIf
\EndFor}
\Statex $P_{GLTP}= \sum_{i=0}^{7} S_P(i)\times 2^i$
\Statex $N_{GLTP}= \sum_{i=0}^{7} S_N(i)\times 2^i$
\Statex \textbf{repeat} for each $3\times3$ neighbourhood
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `\ForAll` is defined within [`algpseudocode`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty) as a block structure with a `S`tart, but no `E`nd:

```
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForAll}[1]{\algorithmicforall\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}%
```

This is important to note, as it plays with the indentation. So, we redefine it to have an `E`nd:

```
\algdef{SE}% Start and End
  [FOR]% New block
  {ForAll}% Creates \ForAll{<stuff>}
  {EndForAll}% Creates \EndForAll
  [1]% One argument passed to \ForAll
  {\algorithmicforall\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}% Text for \ForAll
  {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicforall}% Text for \EndForAll
\algtext*{EndForAll}% Remove text associated with \EndForAll
```

and also remove the `E`nd text (since you're using the `noend` package option). The above combination is similar to

```
\algdef{SN}[FOR]{ForAll}{EndForAll}[1]{\algorithmicforall\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}%
```

Next, I redefine the way your `\skipnumber` macro works. Instead of supplying a number, let's define two switches - `\stopnumbering` and `\resumenumbering` - that deactivates and reactivates line numbering. It makes the codes more readable, I think.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,amsmath}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\let\oldState\State
\newcommand*{\stopnumbering}{%
  \let\olditem\item
  \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{\olditem[]}%
  \let\State\Statex}
\newcommand*{\resumenumbering}{%
  \let\item\olditem
  \let\State\oldState}

\algdef{SE}[FOR]{ForAll}{EndForAll}[1]{\algorithmicforall\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicforall}%
\algtext*{EndForAll}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h!]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    %SOME OTHER STUFF HERE
    \State \textbf{Apply threshold of $\pm t$ around centre gradient value ($G_c$) in
      a $3\times3$ neighbourhood to determine $S_{\text{GLTP}}$ codes for the image}

    \stopnumbering
    \ForAll{gradient magnitude value ($G_i$) around $G_c$}
      \If{$G_i > G_c + t$} $S_{\text{GLTP}}(i) \gets +1$
      \ElsIf{$G_i < G_c - t$}  $S_{\text{GLTP}}(i) \gets -1$
      \Else{} $S_{\text{GLTP}}(i) \gets 0$
      \EndIf
    \EndForAll

    \Statex \textbf{repeat} for each $3 \times 3$ neighbourhood

    \resumenumbering
    \State \textbf{Compute positive ($P_{\text{GLTP}}$) and negative ($N_{\text{GLTP}}$) $\text{GLTP}$   
      coded image representations from $S_{\text{GLTP}}$ values}
    \stopnumbering

    \ForAll{$S_{\text{GLTP}}(i)$ value in a $3 \times 3$ neighbourhood}
      \If {$S_{\text{GLTP}}(i)>0$} $S_P(i) \gets 1$ \& $S_N(i) \gets 0$
      \ElsIf {$S_{\text{GLTP}}(i)<0$} $S_P(i) \gets 0$ \& $S_N(i) \gets 1$
      \Else{} $S_P(i) \gets 0$ \& $S_N(i) \gets 0$
      \EndIf
    \EndForAll

    \Statex $P_{\text{GLTP}} = \sum_{i=0}^{7} S_P(i) \times 2^i$
    \Statex $N_{\text{GLTP}} = \sum_{i=0}^{7} S_N(i) \times 2^i$
    \Statex \textbf{repeat} for each $ 3\times 3$ neighbourhood
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```